# Cheapest way to get to/from Budapest Ferenc Liszt International Airport

Tags: budget, airport-transfer, hungary, budapest, bud

What is the cheapest way to get from Budapest Ferenc Liszt International Airport to the city center and approx. How long does it take?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Terminal 1 (the LCC terminal), you can take a [direct local train](http://www.bud.hu/english/passengers/access_and_parking/by_train) to Nyugati station in the city center in 23 minutes for 365 HUF.

From Terminal 2 (used by everybody else), your best bet is to take [bus 200E](http://www.bud.hu/english/passengers/access_and_parking/by_public_transportation) to Kőbánya-Kispest and connect to the metro (Line 3).  A through ticket is 320F in advance, or 400F from the driver.

Comment: It appears that Terminal 1 is no longer in use.

Comment: Tickets for the metro are also good for the 220E bus.